# What are the blessings of praying in a specific spot in the Prophet's mosque?

Tags: salat, prophet-muhammad, masjid

When my mother when on Umrah, she prayed at this spot where loads of people wanted to pray there and she said it was 'very nice'. My cousin who is a Hafiz told my aunts who went Umrah last year to pray there, even if there is a tiny gap that you could if in to. I wondered if this spot was the spot mentioned in this hadith:

> A’ishah ((P.B.U.H.).A.) reports that Rasulullah (P.B.U.H.) said: “**In this Masjid is one such spot that if people knew the true blessed nature thereof, they would flock towards it in such a manner, that to pray there they would have to cast lots to get a turn (Arabic for casting lots is Qur'ah).**” People asked her to point out the exact spot. When she did not answer they sent her nephew Abdullah ibn Zubayr. They watched him as he performed Salah at the same spot. They also watched his son Amir also perform Salah at that spot. It was on this that they marked this spot as being the one A’ishah ((P.B.U.H.).A.) had mentioned.
>
> [at-Tabarani]

If it is, what are the blessings of praying in this spot?

Another hadith is:

> ببن قبري و منبري روضة من رياض الجنة
>
> “The area between my grave and my minbar is one of the gardens of Paradise.”
>
> Al-Mu‘jam al-Awsat by at-Tabaraani (vol. 2, p. 120).

Comment: There's also the famous hadith ببن قبري و منبري روضة من رياض الجنة

Comment: The more correct version: مَا بَيْنَ بَيْتِي وَمِنْبَرِي رَوْضَةٌ مِنْ رِيَاضِ الْجَنَّةِ   is present in almost all hadith collections https://www.sunnah.com/urn/504670, https://www.sunnah.com/muslim/15/574, https://www.sunnah.com/bukhari/81/176 ... it seems that ibn 'Asakir has a narration of sahih al-Bukhari with the more famous wording, which is not exact, but a narration by meaning! As the house meant was the one of 'Aisha where the Prophet () has been buried!